# Solving lagrangian maximations with summations

Tags: linear-algebra, lagrange-multiplier

The first order condition of my maximization problem is the following:

$(1-t_{i})(1-\gamma \frac{S_{i}}{B_ {i}}) -\lambda$  for all i=1...,n

Solving for S should give:

$S_ {i}=(\frac {B_ {i}} { \gamma (1-t_ {i})})\frac {\sum_{k\neq i}^n (\frac {B_ {k}} {1-t_ {k}})(t_ {k}-t_ {i})} {\sum_{k=1}^n (\frac {B_ {k}} {1-t_ {k}})}$

I found the solution in a paper, however I do not know how one goes from the first equation to the second. Can anybody explain the steps required to solve it?

Comment: It would helpful if you gave a reference / link to the paper you mentioned so people can see it...

Comment: Sure, the full paper is available here: https://ec.europa.eu/economy_finance/publications/pages/publication590_en.pdf